# Android bluetooth le fails to write descriptor due to encryption issue

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to determine what is going wrong in an app that uses bluetooth low energy to communicate with a BLE-capable device. The maddening part is, the problem only occurres on certain devices, like Motorola Moto G3 from Europa and Samsung S5 from China while it works fine with Samsung S5 from Europa, HTC One M7 from Europa and MI W3 from China.

When it is not working, everything stops after a successful write of a descriptor because the corresponding onDescritorWrite(...) callback is never invoked. Presumably it has something to do with the failure to setup encryption (full log below):

```
W/bt-btif (18797): btif_gatt_set_encryption_cb() - Encryption failed (1)
```

I have gone thru the usual things like ensuring bluetooth event are posted to handler on the main thread and now I need new ideas to try to solve this...

My log capturing command:

```
adb logcat | grep 'BLEService\|BluetoothGatt\|BtGatt\|bt\-'
```

Output from the log:

```
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): registerClient() - UUID=9a90904a-84e8-4f30-9b10-de78ac49f236
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onClientRegistered() - UUID=9a90904a-84e8-4f30-9b10-de78ac49f236, clientIf=5
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): start scan with filters
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): handling starting scan
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
E/bt-btm  (18797): Device already in IRK list
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): stopScan() - queue size =1
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): stop scan
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
D/BtGatt.ScanManager(18797): configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
V/BLEService(21323):  - connecting....
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): connect() - device: F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): registerApp() - UUID=4b8c32a4-4a74-49ff-a43f-a769c8200ab8
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): registerClient() - UUID=4b8c32a4-4a74-49ff-a43f-a769c8200ab8
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onClientRegistered() - UUID=4b8c32a4-4a74-49ff-a43f-a769c8200ab8, clientIf=5
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): clientConnect() - address=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87, isDirect=true
E/bt-btm  (18797): Device already in IRK list
W/bt-btm  (18797): btm_acl_created hci_handle=4 link_role=0  transport=2
W/bt-btif (18797): info:x0
W/bt-l2cap(18797): L2CA_SetDesireRole() new:x1, disallow_switch:0
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): client onConnected() - clientIf=5, connId=5, address=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87
V/BLEService(21323): Service have changed with old status: 0 and new status: 2
V/BLEService(21323):  - discovering....
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): discoverServices() - device: F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): discoverServices() - address=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87, connId=5
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onSearchCompleted() - connId=5, status=0
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): onSearchComplete() = Device=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87 Status=0
V/BLEService(21323): Service have discovered with status: 0
V/BLEService(21323):  - discovered....
D/BluetoothGatt(21323): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: f048abf6-3315-4d59-bad7-7e23ac18ee85 enable: true
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): registerForNotification() - address=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87 enable: true
D/BtGatt.GattService(18797): onRegisterForNotifications() - address=null, status=0, registered=1, charUuid=f048abf6-3315-4d59-bad7-7e23ac18ee85
I/BTConnectionReceiver(21037): onReceive(context, Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.search.core.service.BluetoothConnectionReceiver (has extras) }, [BluetoothDevice: address=F4:B8:5E:51:A2:87, alias=null, name=BLEDevice, majorDeviceClass=7936, deviceClass=7936]
I/BluetoothClassifier(21037): Bluetooth Device Name: BLEDevice
W/bt-btif (18797): btif_gatt_set_encryption_cb() - Encryption failed (1)
W/bt-smp  (18797): io_cap = 4
W/bt-smp  (18797): new io_cap = 4 p_cb->loc_enc_size = 16
E/bt-smp  (18797): LTK ready
W/bt-smp  (18797): smp_send_enc_info
W/bt-smp  (18797): smp_send_id_info
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=2 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=2 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=16 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=16 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=16 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=2 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=2 
E/bt-btif (18797): bta_dm_gatt_disc_result serivce_id len=16 
W/bt-btif (18797): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0008
W/bt-btif (18797): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0008
W/bt-btif (18797): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0008
E/bt-btm  (18797): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
```

I would appreciate if someone with some insight could help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A refactoring of the BLE handling code revealed a few steps that were handled incorrectly, which clouded the real issue.

Handling every step correctly allowed the `onDescriptorWrite` callback to be invoked with a status of `BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION` which was indicated by the log.

When the status `BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_ENCRYPTION` is received you need to register for bonding events so you can retry once the bonding is over like so:

```
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Where the receiver (subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`) contains something like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    final int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
    final int previousBondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action) && bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
        // retry
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what type of 'refactoring' you ended up doing to make this work. I'm getting the same issue with a device with 4 BLE services & bonding. Trying to set notification on one characteristic and device disconnects. onDescriptorWrite is never called back. Thx.

Comment: Trying to make out how BLE on Android works had lead to unmaintainable code and the refactoring to a cleaner code base revealed somethings that were done either out of order or more times than intended.